# GIT: For http/https cloned repos only: git push failure shows password in clear text

Tags: git

We are using https to clone a repo as following through Jenkins build:

```
git clone https://${repo_username}:${repo_password}@internalgit.com/scm/project/repo.git -b ${branch_name} $tmp
```

In above command: ${repo_username} & ${repo_password} are Jenkins variables passed as secrets so they are not logged as clear text.

However, this adds the user credentials to the git remote URL and in case of any push failure it shows the credentials in clear text in the following error:

```
[ERROR] To https://user:password@internalgit.com/scm/project/repo.git
[ERROR]  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
[ERROR] error: failed to push some refs to 'https://user:password@internalgit.com/scm/project/repo.git'
```

There can be a number of valid reasons for a push failure, however, printing credentials on screen is not acceptable.

Is there a way either to:

- mask the above error message.
- updating the remote URL to lose the password, without the password once again being prompted during push.

Following work arounds work but NOT acceptable in our use case:

- Store password in credential cache (using credential.helper)
- Using ssh clones instead of https.

Comment: What workflow do you have where output is visible but input is not?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that output is visible but input is not:
<del>`git clone https://${repo_username}:${repo_password}@internalgit.com/scm/project/repo.git -b ${branch_name} $tmp | sed "s/${repo_password}/<redacted>/g"`
 should do what you want.</del>

I misread the question; for this answer to work you'd have to run it on each push (i.e. `git push 2>&1 | sed "s/${repo_password}/<redacted>/g"`. I also missed that git prints this to `stderr`, so unless you want to use [process substition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe), it will be difficult to redirect output.

You should escape the password in case it contains any special regex characters (as otherwise sed may match more or less than you mean too). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/2468549) has some ready solutions for escaping strings to use with sed.

Comment: One caveat is that if password contains any characters with special meaning in regex (of which `*` is reasonably likely) the regex may fail to actually match the password and still reveal it. As for redirecting the output, alternative would be to redirect stdout to a temporary file and then immediately print it out.

Comment: very good point, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/) for info about escaping characters.

Comment: Nice link. I suggested an edit to add it directly to the answer for better visibility.